# VB .NET SQL Time field record update through TextBox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I have a simple Form with four objects: two *TextBoxes*, a *DataGridView* and a *Button*. Through that button I load some data from an SQL database in those objects. The table has two fields, a text field ("MyOtherTextField") and a time field ("MyTimeField"). The code that I have written for the binding is the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim m_dt As DataTable

  Dim m_da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
  Dim m_cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
  Dim m_SelectCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Dim m_InsertCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Dim m_UpdateCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Dim m_DeleteCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Dim m_bmb As BindingManagerBase

  m_dt = New DataTable

  m_cn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("My SQL Connection")

  m_SelectCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("My Command String ", m_cn)

  m_SelectCmd.CommandTimeout = 500
  m_da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(m_SelectCmd)

  m_da.Fill(m_dt)

  If m_dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then

    TextBox3.DataBindings.Clear()
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear()

    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("text", m_dt, "MyTimeField")
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", m_dt, "MyOtherTextField")

    TextBox3.Text = " "
    TextBox1.Text = " "

  Else
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Clear()
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear()

    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("text", m_dt, "MyTimeField")
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", m_dt, "MyOtherTextField")
  End If

  m_bmb = BindingContext(m_dt)

  Dim CmdBuilder As SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(m_da)

  m_InsertCmd = CmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand
  m_UpdateCmd = CmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
  m_DeleteCmd = CmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand

  m_da.InsertCommand = m_InsertCmd
  m_da.UpdateCommand = m_UpdateCmd
  m_da.DeleteCommand = m_DeleteCmd

  ' DataGridView column setup
  MyDataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
  With MyDataGridView
    .AutoGenerateColumns = False

    .ColumnCount = 2

    .Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "MyOtherTextField"
    .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Other Text Field Header Text"
    .Columns(0).Width = 165

    .Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "MyTimeField"
    .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Time Field Header Text"
    .Columns(1).Width = 90
  End With

  MyDataGridView.DataSource = m_dt

  m_cn.Close()
End Sub
```

The data loading works, editing data works both in the DataGridView and in the TextBox1 (the one associated with the text field of the SQL table), but not in the TextBox linked to the time field. So, if I edit the field MyOtherTextField through the TextBox1 it correctly updates that record, but the same thing does not happen for MyTimeField through the TextBox3. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the column type for "myTimeField"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use masked edited text box for time field so you can set the format according to your needs.